# Wordpress admin stop working after putting ssl on domain

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have hosted my website on AWS EC2 Instance, everything was working fine until I added SSL to my website as soon I added SSL it breaks the admin panel of my site

what I did is

1) Got SSL certificate from AWS certificate 
2) Configure it with cloudfront 
3) Also configured in recordset of Route53

My website working fine with the https but admin panel breaks, I have updated all the links in DB to https still I am not sure why its breaking my admin panel and also not let me login inside WP.

[Admin panel breaks screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVuGr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change your site URL by adding `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITE_URL` to [`wp-config.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yoursite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yoursite.com');
```

If that doesn't work try to add the following code.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Make sure to include it before this line.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, we already did it but still it is not working